# Facebook SDK with Unity iOS game not showing friends in leaderboard

Tags: ios, facebook, unity-game-engine, leaderboard

I made an unity game app that using Facebook SDK 7.0.2 for leader board scene. When I tested it with test users, it shows all friends and their high scores. But when I published my app to App Store and logged in with real Facebook Account, I accidentally posting permission to 'Only Me'.

I have looked through all questions about this but none of them help me fix the issue.

I know that it won't post my high score to anyone's leader board, so I changed the permission back to 'Public'. Then I test it again with my friend, I still can't see his score and he still can't see my score too.

below is the screenshot when I tested with test users.
[image]

*when I tested with real user, I can see only my own name and score.

Here's what I have done...

- Get Approval from Facebook for 'publish_actions'
- Try switching between 'Public' and 'Only me'
- Try uninstall and reinstall

I have followed this tutorial to do this kind of thing
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Xt5ae7GUx8

Please help I'm kinda newbie about this kind of API thing.

Thanks in advance,
Puck

Comment: I've tested with Android version and it showed only friends, no high scores.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this by Uninstall Facebook 7.0.2 SDK and Re-import it again.